# Nexus 7 Spinners too large

Tags: android, spinner

I have had a user with a Nexus 7 feed back to me to say my app screens appear as expected except for my `Spinners`, which appear much much larger than they should do.

Normal screen
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLaII.jpg

Large spinners on Nexus 7
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgQ1d.jpg

I have a `Spinner` `TextView` layout:

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_height="36dip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:textSize="24.5sp"
    android:textColor="#768766"
/>
```

which is produced by this `RelativeLayout`:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner_weekday1"
    android:layout_below="@id/col1day"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:prompt="@string/enterday"
    android:layout_width="200dip"
    android:entries="@array/weekdaylist"
    android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
    android:textSize="24.5sp"
    android:textColor="#768766"
/>
```

I have the app running on a range of other devices and it seems fine. Any ideas why the Nexus 7 might display `Spinners` in this way?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I have found the solution to this.

The Spinner layout I posted above was actually the Spinner from res/layout-xlarge and the Nexus is a large devices. The res/layout-large included the following xml:

```
android:textSize="200sp"
```

when it should have been:

```
android:textSize="20sp"
```

and this was of course why the spinner text was appearing so large.

I guess this highlights the difficulty of trying to manage multiple layout sizes without having a physical test device for each.